# Comparador - PriorityQueue

Tags: java

Estou a construir um comparador para depois usar dentro de uma PriorityQueue.

```
private PriorityQueue<Conta> listaOrdenada = new PriorityQueue<Conta>(new ComparadorConta());
```

O objeto que quero ordenar é a Conta.

```
 Conta conta = new Conta(String designação, int numero);

 new Conta("A",2);
 new Conta("B",3);
 new Conta("B",6);
 new Conta("A",1);
 new Conta("A",5);
```

O suposto é ordenar segundo o seguinte critério:

1. Tem de vir os que tem um numero inferior a 4
2. Tem de vir os que começam com a letra A
3. Ordem de inserção

Isto daria este ouput:

"A",2

"A",1

"B",3

"B",6

"A",5

Só que só sei ordenar por número.

```
public class ComparadorConta implements Comparator<Conta>{

 @Override
 public int compare(Conta a, Conta b) {

    return a.getNumero() - b.getNumero();
 }
}
```

Alguem me pode ajudar a ordenar por estes critérios? Obrigado!

Comment: Só uma coisa cara. Pra acessar o atributo `numero` você usa um método mesmo? `numero()`?

Comment: por acaso ate era get numero, ja mudei

Comment: Nesse teu exemplo a ordem correta final não seria: "A",2
"B",3
"A",1
"A",5
"B",6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 1 - Com PriorityQueue**

Caso realmente precise usar `PriorityQueue` para ordenar, sugiro a criação de uma variável de controle para saber a ordem de inserção.

Crie uma variável de classe para controlar o último inserido dentro da classe `Conta`:

```
private static int ultimo = 0;
```

Crie um atributo `ordem` que será utilizado internamente:

```
private final int ordem;
```

No construtor, instancie a ordem e atualize a variável `ultimo`:

```
this.ordem = ultimo + 1;
ultimo = this.ordem;
```

Adicione o `get` do campo `ordem`:

```
public int getOrdem() {
  return ordem;
}
```

Para fazer a comparação, você não precisa de um `Comparator`, apenas que a sua classe `Conta` implemente a `interface` `Comparable` da seguinte forma:

```
public class Conta implements Comparable<Conta> {
```

Você precisará implementar o método `compareTo` que ficará como o seguinte, respeitando as 3 regras impostas no tópico:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Conta conta) {

  // 1. Tem de vir os que tem um numero inferior a 4
  if (this.numero < 4 && conta.getNumero() >= 4) {
    return -1;
  } else if (this.numero >= 4 && conta.getNumero() < 4) {
    return 1;
  }

  // 2. Tem de vir os que começam com a letra A
  if (this.designacao.toUpperCase().startsWith("A") && !conta.getDesignacao().toUpperCase().startsWith("A")) {
    return -1;
  } else if (!this.designacao.toUpperCase().startsWith("A") && conta.getDesignacao().toUpperCase().startsWith("A")) {
    return 1;
  }

  // 3. Ordem de inserção
  return Integer.valueOf(this.ordem).compareTo(conta.getOrdem());
}
```

Para testar utilize:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  PriorityQueue<Conta> listaOrdenada = new PriorityQueue<>();

  listaOrdenada.add(new Conta("A", 2));
  listaOrdenada.add(new Conta("B", 3));
  listaOrdenada.add(new Conta("B", 6));
  listaOrdenada.add(new Conta("A", 1));
  listaOrdenada.add(new Conta("A", 5));

  while(!listaOrdenada.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(listaOrdenada.poll());
  }
}
```

Lembrando que a estrutura que você está utilizando (`PriorityQueue`) reorganiza os itens após o `poll`.

Isso resultará em:

- "A",2
- "A",1
- "B",3
- "A",5
- "B",6

**Sem PriorityQueue**

Acredito que usar o `Collections.sort` e `PriorityQueue` não seja a melhor escolha pelo fato de já existir uma estrutura com o requisito `3` que é a ordem de inserção. O `LinkedHashSet`.
Colocarei aqui duas implementações e o teste das duas é realizado com o seguinte código:

```
LinkedHashSet<Conta> lista = new LinkedHashSet<>();
LinkedHashSet<Conta> listaOrdenada;

lista.add(new Conta("A", 2));
lista.add(new Conta("B", 3));
lista.add(new Conta("B", 6));
lista.add(new Conta("A", 1));
lista.add(new Conta("A", 5));

listaOrdenada = this.ordenar(lista);

for (Conta conta : listaOrdenada) {
  System.out.println(conta);
}
```

Onde a classe conta possui o método `toString` seguinte:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "\"" + this.designacao + "\"," + String.valueOf(this.numero); 
}
```

A primeira considera apenas as 3 regras isoladas:

```
public LinkedHashSet<Conta> ordenar(LinkedHashSet<Conta> lista) {
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> prioridade1 = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // Números menores que 4
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> prioridade2 = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // Letra "A"
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> restante = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> listaOrdenada = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  for (Conta conta : lista) {
    if (conta.getNumero() < 4) {
      prioridade1.add(conta);
    } else if (conta.getDesignacao().toUpperCase().startsWith("A")) {
      prioridade2.add(conta);
    } else {
      restante.add(conta);
    }
  }

  listaOrdenada.addAll(prioridade1);
  listaOrdenada.addAll(prioridade2);
  listaOrdenada.addAll(restante);

  return listaOrdenada;
}
```

Resultando em:

- "A",2
- "B",3
- "A",1
- "A",5
- "B",6

A segunda considera que os números menores que 4 e com letra "A" tem prioridade máxima:

```
public LinkedHashSet<Conta> ordenar(LinkedHashSet<Conta> lista) {
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> prioridade1 = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // Números menores que 4 com letra "A"
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> prioridade2 = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // Números menores que 4
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> prioridade3 = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // Letra "A"
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> restante = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  LinkedHashSet<Conta> listaOrdenada = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  for (Conta conta : lista) {
    if (conta.getNumero() < 4
            && conta.getDesignacao().toUpperCase().startsWith("A")) {
      prioridade1.add(conta);
    } else if (conta.getNumero() < 4) {
      prioridade2.add(conta);
    } else if (conta.getDesignacao().toUpperCase().startsWith("A")) {
      prioridade3.add(conta);
    } else {
      restante.add(conta);
    }
  }

  listaOrdenada.addAll(prioridade1);
  listaOrdenada.addAll(prioridade2);
  listaOrdenada.addAll(prioridade3);
  listaOrdenada.addAll(restante);

  return listaOrdenada;
}
```

Resultando em:

- "A",2
- "A",1
- "B",3
- "A",5
- "B",6

Caso seja necessário usar `PriorityQueue` você pode fazer a conversão a seguir:

```
PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue();
pq.addAll(listaOrdenada);
```

Comment: Mas e quanto aos critérios 1 e 3? A comparação entre letras realmente funciona, porém a de números não parece se encaixar

Comment: Começa pelo número né? Fiz invertido. Mas ta ali o compareTo do numero também

Comment: pois é isso, eu preciso dos 3 critérios. E esse só dá as letras.

Comment: @Sorack Acontece que seu código não compara se é menor que 4, e também não compara os objetos pela ordem de inserção, como deveria.

Comment: Alterei para corresponder exatamente ao que foi perguntado

Comment: Obrigado! Mas tenho mesmo de resolver isto com priority queue

Comment: Você pode dar um PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue();
pq.addAll(listaOrdernada); para transformar depois

Comment: sim, mas sem usar linkedhash é que é suposto.

Comment: Verifique o `Edit 1` com a implementação necessária para que seu problema seja resolvido com `PriorityQueue`

Answer (score 1):

Para ordenar com uma ou mais campos funciona assim, supondo 3 campos no seu caso é dois.

**Lição 1:** conforme aumenta o numero de campos aumenta o numero e quando retorna zero é que ele não muda de posição, **isso faz com que avance ou recue a posição do item na coleção**

```
 1
 2
 3
 0
-1
-2
-3
```

**Lição 2**: Implementar a interface **java.lang.Comparable**

Fazendo a implementação conforme necessário, somente do methodo

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object object)
{
    Conta bean = (Conta) object;
    int result=0;
    if (this.getId() < bean.getId())
    {
        result = -1;
    }
    else if (this.getNumero() < bean.getNumero)
    {
        result = -2;
    }
    else if (this.getDescricao() < bean.getDescricao())
    {
        result = -3;
    }else if (this.getId() > bean.getId())
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else if (this.getNumero() > bean.getNumero)
    {
        result = 2;
    }
    else if (this.getDescricao() > bean.getDescricao())
    {
        result = 3;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Lição 3:**  Trate as condições conforme sua necessidade. depois é só usar, **clean code**

> Collections.sort(contas);